# Extracting rows from data, if actual and following value of the row in only one special column isn't the same

Tags: r, select, dataframe, extract, rows

I have the following problem in using R:
I have a data with a running timestamp so there are many rows. 
In case of a change in "direction" the whole row before and after the change should be extracted in a new table.

Example:
What I have:

Timestamp   direction   …
00:01   front   …
00:02   front   …
00:03   front   …
**00:04 front   …

00:05   side    …**
00:06   side    …
00:07   side    …
00:08   side    …
**00:09 side    …

00:10   front   …**
00:11   front   …
00:12   front   …
**00:13 front   …

00:14   back    …**
00:15   back    …
00:16   back    …
00:17   back    …
00:18   back    …
00:19   back    …

What I want as a new table:

Timestamp   direction   …
00:04   front   …
00:05   side    …
00:09   side    …
00:10   front   …
00:13   front   …
00:14   back    …

Who can help me? I dont really know where to start.
I import the data with `data <- read.table` so I have 20 variables and more then 50000 observations.

One out of many examples I tried but couldn't finish:

```
row <- nrow(data)
for (r in 1:row) {
  if (r != r+1)
```

--> How can I apply not to the whole row but only to that one variable but extract the whole row if r!=2+1 ??

Also one try I couldnt finish:
[Extracting row from a data frame according a criterion based if values through rows changed or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743957/extracting-row-from-a-data-frame-according-a-criterion-based-if-values-through-r)
The first part of this question is close to mine but than I have only one "fisher"/proband and I need not a table with new variables but the whole old row with my 20 variables.

Comment: It's more likely that we will be able to help you if you provide a [complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to answer your question. I will also recommend to take a look at the [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It's also generally good to demonstrate you already put some effort into it.

Answer (score 1):

`dplyr::lag` and `dplyr::lead` are useful for accessing previous and following elements in vectors. Below is a solution using these, as well as other data wrangling tools in the [`dplyr` package](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) (if you're unfamiliar with the package, see e.g. [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html) for an introduction); see the comments for details.

```r
library(dplyr)

new <- df %>% 
  # find rows where direction is different from direction on previous row
  mutate(..change = direction != lag(direction)) %>%
  # keep rows where direction changed, as well as the row before each change
  filter(..change | lead(..change)) %>% 
  # drop the change indicator from the data
  select(-..change)

new
#>   Timestamp direction
#> 1     00:04     front
#> 2     00:05      side
#> 3     00:09      side
#> 4     00:10     front
#> 5     00:13     front
#> 6     00:14      back

all.equal(new, want)
#> [1] TRUE
```

**Edit:** You could also drop the `mutate` and `select` by using an approach analogous to @storaged's elegant answer:

```r
new <- df %>% 
  filter(direction != lag(direction) | direction != lead(direction))
```

PS. For the above, I read in the data snippets you provided like this:

```r
op <- options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
Timestamp direction
00:01 front
00:02 front
00:03 front
00:04 front
00:05 side
00:06 side
00:07 side
00:08 side
00:09 side
00:10 front
00:11 front
00:12 front
00:13 front
00:14 back
00:15 back
00:16 back
00:17 back
00:18 back
00:19 back
")

want <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
Timestamp direction
00:04 front
00:05 side
00:09 side
00:10 front
00:13 front
00:14 back
")

options(op)
```

Answer (score 1):

`dplyr` looks cool, but I also suggest something simple basing on logical operations:

Assuming your second column contains the direction (i.e. `data[,2]`)
I would do:

```
x <- data[,2]
y <- c(x[1], x[1:(length(x)-1)])
z <- c(x[2:length(x)], x[1])
```

and the rows you need are:

```
data[(x != y | x != z),]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you two for your support!
Unfortunatly I had some problems with installing and using packages so I couldn't try @MikkoMarttilas solution. Just with the @storaged code I also didn't get what I needed but I combined the idea with the one in my answer so this is what worked for me:

```
data <- read.table()
dat7 <- data[,7]
num.dat7 <- c(dat7[1], dat7[1:(length(dat7))])
w <- which(diff(num.dat7)!=0)
w1 <- w-1
after <- data.frame(data[w,])
before <- data.frame(data[w1,])
bind <- rbind(before, after)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `lag()` and `lead()` to identify changes in `direction` we can use `rleid()` to group by continuous streaks of identical values of `direction` and pick the first and last value of each streak:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df[, .I[c(1L, .N)], by = rleid(direction)]$V1][-c(1L, .N)]
```

Finally, the first row of the first streak and the last row of the last streak are removed from the result as requested by the OP.

> ```
>    Timestamp direction
> 1:     00:04     front
> 2:     00:05      side
> 3:     00:09      side
> 4:     00:10     front
> 5:     00:13     front
> 6:     00:14      back
> ```